# C++ MySQL Connector no utf8

Tags: c++, mysql

I have a problem getting UTF-8 strings from MySQL database. I use C++ connector 1.1 and connect with following code:

```
sql::ConnectOptionsMap connection_properties;
connection_properties["hostName"] = server;
connection_properties["userName"] = user;
connection_properties["password"] = password;
connection_properties["schema"] = database;
connection_properties["port"] = 3306;
connection_properties["OPT_CHARSET_NAME"] = "utf8";
connection_properties["characterSetResults"] = "utf8";
connection_properties["preInit"] = "SET NAMES utf8";

driver = get_driver_instance();
con = driver->connect(connection_properties);
con->setSchema(database);
```

I already tried different utf8 options as you see....

If a statement should return database strings like "アフガニスタン" I only see chars like this "ã‚¢ãƒ•ã‚¬ãƒ‹ã‚¹ã‚¿ãƒ³" when I use Visual Studio debugger. The observed code:

```
std::string name = res->getString(2);
```

After Json encode it prints "ÒéóÒâòÒé¼ÒâïÒé╣Òé┐Òâ│" into command line.

Other utf8 columns with normal latin characters are returned as expected. It only affects translation columns with non latin chars.

Same database call from PHP with same logic (db connection and json encode) on same PC prints out following chars "\u30a2\u30d5\u30ac\u30cb\u30b9\u30bf\u30f3".

Any ideas about that?

Comment: What C++ string type are you using?

Comment: That’s how UTF-8 looks, so the code is fine. Have you tried saving the JSON into a file and reading it as UTF-8? The different result from PHP is due to it *not* handling the strings as UTF-8 but as actual character data.

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen thank you. Your are right. I wrote this output to file and all UTF-8 characters are correct. Damn...hours spent on nothing. C++ and UTF-8 is evil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is no problem. I wrote returned data into a file and all UTF-8 characters are correct. Debugger and CMD are not able to display UTF-8 data as expected...